# Integrar RDStation com Django + Python p/ envio de lead

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, django, integração

Bom dia galera, estou com um problema:

estou com uma LP que tem que salvar o lead no banco do Postgres e enviar automaticamente esse lead para a plataforma do RD usando a API deles.

usando o *`curl`* eu faço da seguinte forma:

```
curl -v \
      -X POST \
      -H "Content-type: application/json" \
      -d '{ "email": "meuemail@gmail.com",
            "name": "raphael melo de lima", 
            "identificador": "form-landing-posp", 
            "token_rdstation": "meu_token_do_rd" 
          }' \
      'https://www.rdstation.com.br/api/1.3/conversions'
```

Assim eu consigo enviar o respectivo lead, porém não estou conseguindo entender como faço isso usando meu método de cadastro no postgres.

Segue minha ***views.py***:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json

def create_lead(request):       
    form = LeadForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        lead = Lead.objects.filter(email=data['email']).first()

        if lead:
            request.session['lead_id'] = lead.id
            return redirect('registrations:videos_list')

        lead = form.save()
        request.session['lead_id'] = lead.id
        return redirect('registrations:videos_list')

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form})

def videos_list(request):

    if 'lead_id' in request.session:
        lead = Lead.objects.get(pk=request.session['lead_id'])


        return render(request, 'videos-list.html')

    return redirect('registrations:create_lead')
```

será que alguém consegue me dar essa força?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando `requests`:

```
import requests

requests.post(
    'https://www.rdstation.com.br/api/1.3/conversions',
    json={
        'email': 'meuemail@gmail.com',
        'name': 'raphael melo de lima',
        'identificador': 'form-landing-posp',
        'token_rdstatuion': "meu_token_do_rd",
    }
)
```

Daí é só colocar isso no seu código, com as variáveis que você quer enviar.... `data['email']` e `data['name']` por exemplo?

Comment: é bem assim mesmo, muito obrigado pela ajuda cara consegui fazer o POST, e fiz uma melhora que achei pertinente `url ="https://www.rdstation.com.br/api/1.3/conversions"
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
        data = {'name':lead.name,
                'email':lead.email,
                'identificador': 'form-landing-posp',
                'token_rdstation': 'meu_token'}
        r = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
        r.json()`

Comment: @RaphaelMeloDeLima Passar `headers` é inútil e reduntante, ao usar o parâmetro `json=` no `requests.post()` o `content-type` é automaticamente configurado para `application/json` sem precisar especificar separadamente, portanto, você deveria remover esse parâmetro e fazer como na minha resposta.